# Hibernate mapping error after moving to Maven project

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, maven, backend

my problem is mapping entities using SessionFactory. My project had been working before I moved it on Maven project. Now when I create project using Maven commands, my project has problem with mapping entities.
I use SessionFactory with hibernate.cfg.xml file. In it I mapped all entities.
In entity I import javax.persistence.Entity.
Do you know any other possible problems?

[EDIT]
My config file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/report_db</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>


        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup 
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>-->

        <!-- Mappings -->
        <mapping class="com.bombardier.raportcreator.database.entity.impl.Lastfile" />
        <mapping class="com.bombardier.raportcreator.database.entity.impl.Project" />
        <mapping class="com.bombardier.raportcreator.database.entity.impl.Costcenter" />
        <mapping class="com.bombardier.raportcreator.database.entity.impl.Month" />
        <mapping class="com.bombardier.raportcreator.database.entity.impl.Resource" />
        <mapping class="com.bombardier.raportcreator.database.entity.impl.Role" />
        <mapping class="com.bombardier.raportcreator.database.entity.impl.Task" />
        <mapping class="com.bombardier.raportcreator.database.entity.impl.Tasktocostcenter" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Example entity class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity
    @NamedQuery(name="Lastfile.findAll", query="SELECT l FROM Lastfile l")

public class Lastfile implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private short id;

    private String lastFileName;

    public Lastfile() {
    }

    public short getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(short id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastFileName() {
        return this.lastFileName;
    }

    public void setLastFileName(String lastFileName) {
        this.lastFileName = lastFileName;
    }

}
```

Structure of my project. Pom is main directory of project. Entites are showed.
  [Project structure][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDl6l.png

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.bombardier.raportcreator.database.entity.impl.Lastfile
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1462)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
at com.bombardier.raportcreator.database.dao.DaoImpl.create(DaoImpl.java:20)
at com.bombardier.raportcreator.file.LastFileManager.setLastFileName(LastFileManager.java:34)
at Test.main(Test.java:48)
```

Comment: This is not enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: Yes, I know, just now I added codes. Generally I had project and it was working, after added pom.xml and recreate project using maven mapping stopped working.

Comment: What's the error? Where is the pom?

Comment: I added structure and exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is obvious - chcanged version of Hibernate to the newest (from 4.3.9 to 5.0.4.). I assume that Hibernate changed something in building entity class or mapping them in new version.